# returning controller and action in parseurl CBaseUrlRule

Tags: php, yii

I am not following `CBaseUrlRule` `parseUrl`. Documentation says it returns the controller and action, but Im getting a `Unable to resolve the request "name".`, such that url.com/name, where the original request is `url.com/module/controller/action?id=id&name=name`. So `createUrl` is creating some desirable looking url but it doesn't return to the `controller/action/id`. I definitely don't think I am understanding the entire flow to this. When I `parseurl`, does it look at the created url I have `url.com/name`. If so, how can it ever get the controller and action?

extending from CBaseUrlRule

```
public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        if(preg_match('~^module/controller/action?id=(\d+)~',$pathInfo)){
            $query_string = parse_url($pathInfo, PHP_URL_QUERY);
            parse_str($query_string, $data);
            $id = $data['id'];

            $result = Yii::app()->{$this->connectionID}->createCommand()
                    ->select('table_id')
                    ->from('table')
                    ->where('table_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))
                    ->queryRow();

                if(!empty($result)) {
                    $_GET['id']=$id;
                    return ?;
//don't quiet understand this part? return what? 
//I don't understand why some places they return id, then what happened to my controller and action?
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the controller and the action that you want to run.

For example if your url must run the `NewsController` with `actionIndex` you will return

```
return 'news/index';
```

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseUrlRule#parseUrl-detail)

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I just found out and I was looking for `news/view` and some id.. thinking that I need to put in id too after view return, I don't! Thanks!